# Inconsistent behavior using Pandas at[ ] getting and setting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I might be understanding the usage of Pandas `at` wrong but I can only access a DataFrame to edit it but not correctly read from it.

For example, I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "key": [1, 3, 5, 7],
        "x": [6, 9, 7, 2],
        "y": [2, 4, 7, 10],
    })
print(df)

    key      x      y      
0     1      6      2
1     3      9      4
2     5      7      7
3     7      2      10
```

I have no problem accessing / editing a dataframe using `at`:

```
df.at[df['x'] == 6, 'y'] = 4
print(df)

    key      x      y      
0     1      6      4
1     3      9      4
2     5      7      7
3     7      2      10
```

However, if I'm trying to read the value for the cell:

```
a = df.at[df['x'] == 6, 'y']
print(a)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: '0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: x, dtype: bool' is an invalid key
```

How can this be?

My end goal is to use `at` to get a guaranteed single cell from a Dataframe (vs possibly multiple cells when using loc). Is `at` even what I should be using?

Comment: TLDR: don't use `at`, use `loc`.

Comment: But aren't you suppose to use `at` if you only want to get one value?

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for the tip. But even so why do I get an error in this case?

Comment: AFAIK, people are talking about deprecating `at/iat`. I personally don't use them as they are equivalent to `.loc[one_index, one_column]`.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks!